# Unable to add decimal in input type even after adding step

Tags: html, html-input

I have HTML input which is set to be a numeric input including the up and down carets. To my surprise I am unable to enter any decimal numbers.

```html
<input type="number" />
```

It does not accept such input and jumps back to a non-decimal number. Is there any way I can keep the input type numeric and still allow decimal numbers?

Comment: I have just tried out the problem you are facing in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtogfuvx/) and can not reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `step` attribute to say the number input allow decimal

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow any number of decimal then use this:

```
<input type="number" step="any" />
```

If you want specific like two decimal places then set like this:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
```

Hope it helps!